# MailMerge Data Inside Word Table via VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, interop, mailmerge

```
wrdMergeFields.Add(wrdSelection.Range, "ProductName")
```

The code above basically dispalys all the productName in differents pages in word Document during merge.

Please help me how to put the data inside a table. I have to write multiple codes of this for my ProductName, AccountNo, OutBalance, AccountName, etc. My problem here is that I don't know how to put them in a table.

Comment: What sort of table? A table in your word document or a database table or what?

Comment: Table inside word document. What I am trying to do here is to populate the table with data from the mailmerge. I can dispalay the data yet I can't get to put them cell by cell in the table.

Answer (score 0):

if you are also interested in 3rd party libraries to solve your problem, you can try our [GemBox.Document](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document/overview) component.

Here is a sample VB.NET code how to do it (by creating a template document from the code and by loading it from a file):

```
' Use the component in free mode.
ComponentInfo.SetLicense("FREE-LIMITED-KEY")

' Define DataTable with two columns: 'Name' and 'Surname', and fill it with some data.
' You don't have to do this if you already have a DataTable instance.
Dim dataTable = New DataTable("People")
dataTable.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Name", GetType(String)))
dataTable.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Surname", GetType(String)))
dataTable.Rows.Add("John", "Doe")
dataTable.Rows.Add("Fred", "Nurk")
dataTable.Rows.Add("Hans", "Meier")
dataTable.Rows.Add("Ivan", "Horvat")

' Create and save a template document. 
' You don't have to do this if you already have a template document.
' This code is only provided as a reference how template document should look like.
Dim document = New DocumentModel()
document.Sections.Add(
    New Section(document,
        New Table(document,
            New TableRow(document,
                New TableCell(document,
                    New Paragraph(document, "Name")),
                New TableCell(document,
                    New Paragraph(document, "Surname"))),
            New TableRow(document,
                New TableCell(document,
                    New Paragraph(document,
                        New Field(document, FieldType.MergeField, "RangeStart:People"),
                        New Field(document, FieldType.MergeField, "Name"))),
                New TableCell(document,
                    New Paragraph(document,
                        New Field(document, FieldType.MergeField, "Surname"),
                        New Field(document, FieldType.MergeField, "RangeEnd:People")))))))
document.Save("TemplateDocument.docx", SaveOptions.DocxDefault)

' Load a template document.
document = DocumentModel.Load("TemplateDocument.docx", LoadOptions.DocxDefault)

' Mail merge template document with DataTable.
' Important: DataTable.TableName and RangeStart/RangeEnd merge field names must match.
document.MailMerge.ExecuteRange(dataTable)

' Save the mail merged document.
document.Save("Document.docx", SaveOptions.DocxDefault)

' Open the documents with MS Word.
Process.Start("TemplateDocument.docx")
Process.Start("Document.docx")
```